# How can i delete all cookies from QNetworkAccessManager?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying do it using this code:

```
for(const auto i : Cookies.allCookies())
{
    Cookies.deleteCookie(i);
}
```

But it doesn't work. How can i delete all cookies used by `QNetworkAccessManager`?

Comment: Since the `QNetworkCookieJar` only holds cookies in memory, just create a new cookie jar and assign it to your `QNetworkAccessManager`.

Comment: this is what I've wrote him on other site.